# Detect Debian dist-upgrade versus clean build

Tags: debian, upgrade

I am looking at a Debian server that has version `wheezy/sid`. Is there a way I can tell if this server was upgraded from `squeeze` via `dist-upgrade` versus being built from scratch as a wheezy server?

Comment: Have you checked the log files? E.g. `/var/log/aptitude*`, `/var/log/apt/*`

Comment: Short of the log files you probably have to look for non-upgraded conffiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you can use `apt-get dist-upgrade` to change from one release to another is if you've modified `/etc/apt/sources.list` to point to the new release.

You can check the logs in `/var/log/apt/` and `/etc/apt/sources.list` to see what was done.

Comment: Since when does Debian have do-release-upgrade?  Can you point to somewhere in the official docs saying this is the only supported way to upgrade?

Comment: Lol. Yeah, that was Ubuntu. Sorry, got my distros confused. I've updated it.